# Display image using Jquery "find"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display an image using jquery.I have a function which has ID & PATH as a parameter.The ID indicates the section(Each section is a html page which gets loaded on user action),Also there is a text area where I am displaying the text file content.Now in a same way i want to display image ,I tried different methods but it didn't work out.Below is my Java Script file & HTML file

HTML File:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div  id="tab1"  name="tab" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; width:90px;float: left;height: 22px ; margin-top: 0px;
        background-color:lightgrey;font-size: 13px;text-align: center;border-bottom: none;display: table-cell;"                 onClick="tabs(1)">
        <div style="margin-top: 3px" >TAB1</div>
        </div>
        <div   id="tab2" name="tab" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; width:90px;background-color:lightgrey;float: left;height: 20px; margin-top: 2px; font-size: 12px;text-align: center" onClick="tabs(2)">
        <div style="margin-top: 3px">TAB2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:auto;height: 22px; border-bottom-color: white;border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px"></div>  



        <div name="tab_content"   style="display: block; margin-left:20px;" >
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>   
            <div id="legendReport">
            Notes 1:
            </div>
            <textarea   name="textArea1" rows="4" value="" cols="50"></textarea> 
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>   
            <div id="legendRough">
            Notes 2:
            </div>
            <textarea id="roughNotes_textArea" name="textArea2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>    
        </div> 

        <div name="tab_content"  class="tab_content" style="display: none;margin-left:20px;">
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>                    
            <textarea  name="textArea3" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea>  
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>   
            <textarea  name="textArea4" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>  
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>
            <br></br>   
            <br></br>                           
            <!-- Schematic of selected analysis Point -->
            <img id="myImage" src="" style="width:304px;height:228px;"></img>   
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript File:

```
//Displays the file content in text area
function displayTextfileData(textFilePath,ID){
    readTextFile(textFilePath);
    alert(textFileContent);

    var sectionDIV = "#section" + ID;
    alert(sectionDIV)

    $(sectionDIV).find("[name=textArea3]").val(textFileContent);
    $(sectionDIV).find("[name=textArea4]").val(textFileContent);
}

//This function display the image
function displayImage(imageFilePath,ID){
    var sectionDIV = "#section" + ID;
    alert("displayImageforDropdown():"+imageFilePath);
    //$(sectionDIV).find("myImage").src = imageFilePath;
    $(sectionDIV).getElementById("myImage").src = imageFilePath;
    //document.getElementById("myImage").src = imageFilePath
    //alert("displayImageforDropdown(): Assigned result: "+(document.getElementByName("displayImage").src = imageFilePath));
}
```

Display text file content is working fine,But i want the same on Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`$(sectionDIV).getElementById("myImage").src = imageFilePath;`

with

`$(sectionDIV).find("img#myImage").attr("src", imageFilePath);;`

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting the following console message: TypeError: $(...).getElementById is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can set the '**src**' attribute as following:

```
$(sectionDIV).find("#myImage").prop("src", imageFilePath);
```

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting the following console message:TypeError: $(...).getElementById is not a function

Comment: try the edit, it should be "find" instead of "getElementById"

Comment: this is better: $("#section" + ID + "#myImage").prop("src", imageFilePath);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(sectionDIV)[0].getElementById("myImage").attr("src", imageFilePath);
```

or

```
$(sectionDIV).find("#myImage").attr("src", imageFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(sectionDIV).find("#myImage").attr("src", imageFilePath);
```

Or if you want to use `getElementById` use `$(sectionDIV)[0]` to get the HTML DOM Object from the jQuery Object. Something like,

```
$(sectionDIV)[0].getElementById("myImage").src =  imageFilePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayImage(imageFilePath, ID) {
    var sectionDIV = "#section" + ID;
    //Change this line.....
    $("#myImage",$(sectionDIV))[0].src = imageFilePath;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation about the code would improve your answer drastically.