# Create Tabs with each tab having two textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create two tabs in HTML & on click of each tab it should display two text area (empty),I have already tried this and able to create, but my logic involves for loop to display the text area based on tabs selected .which is not supported for my application,Now i want a simple logic to create and display the text area

My JS code:

```
function tabs(selectedtab) {    
  // contents
var s_tab_content = "tab_content_" + selectedtab;   
//alert(s_tab_content);
var contents = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var x=0; x<contents.length; x++) {
    name = contents[x].getAttribute("name");
    if (name == 'tab_content') {
        if (contents[x].id == s_tab_content) {
        contents[x].style.display = "block";                        
        } else {
        contents[x].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

HTML Code:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div  id="tab1"  name="tab" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; width:90px;
                                float: left;
                                height: 22px ;
                                margin-top: 0px;
                                background-color:lightgrey;
                                font-size: 13px;
                                text-align: center; 
                                border-bottom: none;
                                display: table-cell;" 
                                onClick="tabs(1)">
                                    <div style="margin-top: 3px" >Tab1</div>
            </div>
            <div   id="tab2" name="tab" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; width:90px;background-color:lightgrey;float: left;height: 20px; margin-top: 2px; font-size: 12px;text-align: center" onClick="tabs(2)">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px">Tab2</div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:auto;height: 22px; border-bottom-color: white;border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px"></div>  



            <div name="tab_content" id="tab_content_1"  style="display: block; margin-left:20px;" >
                <br></br>   
                <br></br>   
                <div id="legendReport">
                 Notes 1:
                </div>
                <textarea id="reportNotes_textArea"  name="textArea1" rows="4" value="" cols="50"></textarea> 
                <br></br>   
                <br></br>   
                <div id="legendRough">
                 Notes 2:
                </div>
                <textarea id="roughNotes_textArea" name="textArea2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>    
            </div> 

            <div name="tab_content" id="tab_content_2"  class="tab_content" style="display: none;margin-left:20px;">
                <br></br>   
                <br></br>                    
                <textarea id="geometry_first_textArea" name="textArea3" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea>  
                <br></br>   
                <br></br>   
                <textarea id="geometry_second_textArea" name="textArea4" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>  
                <br></br>   
                <br></br>
                <br></br>   
                <br></br>
                <div id="legendRough">
                    Schematic:      
                </div>

                <img id="myImage" src="" style="width:304px;height:228px;"></img>   

            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please include the code you have already tried.

Comment: does two taps mean two pages?

Comment: @ Velimir Tchatchevsky:No its single HTML page consisting of two tabs

Comment: @Ian: Please check updated code

Comment: Please post also your mark up(HTML).

Comment: Please check  I have added my html code

Comment: Please check I have added my html code

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you're using a `name` attribute to select `<div>` elements. According to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name), divs aren't allowed to have this attribute. Using the `class` attribute would probably better suit your needs.

```
<div class="tab_content" id="tab_content_1">...</div>
<div class="tab_content" id="tab_content_2">...</div>
```

Secondly: if you're going to have *more than 2* tabs, you'll end up having to need some sort of loop. When a new element gets shown, you'll have to be able to hide the others.

If, like in your example, there will only be **2** tabs, you could use `document.querySelector` like so:

```
function tabs(selectedtab) {    
  var s_tab_content = "#tab_content_" + selectedtab;
  var tabToShow = document.querySelector(".tab_content" + s_tab_content);
  var tabToHide = document.querySelector(".tab_content:not(" + s_tab_content + ")");

  // Add your code to hide and show the tabs here:
  // ...
}
```

The first selector selects *the first* element that has *both* the *class* 'tab_content', and the *id* you've stored in `s_tab_content`. The second selector selects the first element that has the class 'tab_content' *without* the id.

My suggestion however would be to keep the loop and solve your problem like so:

1. Select all `tab_content` divs
2. Hide them all
3. Use `document.getElementById` to find the *one* to show
4. Show the one that you need

This will keep working, even if you add many tabs.

Comment: How to hide the tabs can you please give me the Code & I don't want to use for loop which I am using

Comment: You already figured that out yourself! `tabToShow.style.display = "block"; tabToHide.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Have you made the changes to your HTML? This error indicates that finding `tabToShow` didn't work as we intended. I'll make an example for you that works.

Comment: No i didn't make any changes to my HTML

Comment: Here's an example of how it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/fcuy8bcz/ Note that there are many things you can improve in terms of scalability. But for now, I think it's important you understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108942/discussion-between-user3297291-and-ram).

Comment: Actually I have a set of radio buttons(list) based on the selection of a button i am loading the html(which contains tabs) ,each button is given a sectionID,Now the problem is above code is working fine if i select first radio button for rest its not working

Comment: Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351860/display-image-using-jquery-find/36352177?noredirect=1#comment60325661_36352177 my previous question

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by that. I don't see any radio buttons in either of your questions. Please consider formulating a new question if there's a new problem and ask yourself if _this_ question is now correctly answered...